# Spring @async child thread context multitenancy

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, asynchronous, multi-tenant

I have an APP which sends some REST calls to my java application. I have to run the last command in @Async mode, so the user can continue with the use of the app while there is an async task executing one more SOAP call.

The problem is that I have autowired the TenantContext and several tenant identifiers in the database. As the async task is executed it has the tenantcontext of my mainthread and saves the data for the wrong tenant.

This is my JpaTransactionManager which is called for every transaction in the database:

```
@Autowired
private TenantContext tenantContext;

@Autowired
private Flyway flyway;

@Autowired
private Environment environment;

@Override
protected void doBegin(final Object transaction, final TransactionDefinition definition)
{
    super.doBegin(transaction, definition);
    final EntityManagerHolder entityManagerHolder = (EntityManagerHolder) TransactionSynchronizationManager.getResource(getEntityManagerFactory());
    final EntityManager entityManager = entityManagerHolder.getEntityManager();

    String subAccountId = "";
    if (environment.getActiveProfiles().length == 0 || !environment.getActiveProfiles()[0].equals("production"))
    {
        subAccountId = "SCAN4CLOUD";
    } else
    {
        subAccountId = tenantContext.getTenant().getAccount().getId().toUpperCase();
    }

    entityManager.setProperty("tenant", subAccountId);
}
```

I have tried to intercept the async call with the following classes to set the right tenantcontext.

```
@Configuration
@EnableAsync
public class AsyncConfig extends AsyncConfigurerSupport
{
@Autowired
private TenantContext tenantContext;

@Autowired
private Environment environment;

private HashMap<String, ContextAwarePoolExecutor> tenantThreadPoolTaskExecutor = new HashMap<String, ContextAwarePoolExecutor>();

@Override
@Bean
@Scope(value = "request", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
public Executor getAsyncExecutor()
{

    String subAccountId = "";

    if (environment.getActiveProfiles().length == 0 || !environment.getActiveProfiles()[0].equals("production"))
    {
        subAccountId = "SCAN4CLOUD";
    } else
    {
        subAccountId = tenantContext.getTenant().getAccount().getId().toUpperCase();
    }

    if (!tenantThreadPoolTaskExecutor.containsKey(subAccountId))
    {
        tenantThreadPoolTaskExecutor.put(subAccountId, new ContextAwarePoolExecutor(tenantContext));
    }

    return tenantThreadPoolTaskExecutor.get(subAccountId);
}
```

}

ContextAwarePoolExecutor:

```
public class ContextAwarePoolExecutor extends ThreadPoolTaskExecutor
{
    private TenantContext tenantContext;

    public ContextAwarePoolExecutor(TenantContext tenantContext)
    {
        this.tenantContext = tenantContext;
    }

    @Override
    public <T> Future<T> submit(Callable<T> task)
    {
        return super.submit(new ContextAwareCallable(task, tenantContext));
    }

    @Override
    public <T> ListenableFuture<T> submitListenable(Callable<T> task)
    {
        return super.submitListenable(new ContextAwareCallable(task, tenantContext));
    }
}
```

ContextAwareCallable:

```
public class ContextAwareCallable<T> implements Callable<T>
{
private Callable<T> task;
private TenantContext tenantContext;

public ContextAwareCallable(Callable<T> task, TenantContext tenantContext)
{
    this.task = task;
    this.tenantContext = tenantContext;
}

@Override
public T call() throws Exception
{
    if (tenantContext != null)
    {
        return tenantContext.execute(tenantContext.getTenant().getId(), task);
    }

    return task.call();
    }
}
```

But it still doesn't give me the correct tenant of the parent thread.

Any suggestions or another approach for this?

Thanks,
nosTa

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it by passing adding the tenantid directly in the contextawarecallable constructor. now it's working.

Comment: But you are passing tenantContext already in the constructor which should have tenantId identified already. How did this help you?

Comment: I should have posted some code explanation because I also don't know what was in my mind while writing this. I just know that I had some problems accessing the tenantcontext so I created a variable in ContextAwareCallable private String tenantid and passed the tenant id in the constructor. But I'm not sure why I had some issues there.

Comment: Can you please post the correction that you have made? And can you also post the TenantContext class?

Answer (score 0):

Tenantcontext class is coming from SAP: import com.sap.cloud.account.TenantContext;
https://appdoc.app/artifact/com.sap.cloud/neo-java-web-api/1.105.21/com/sap/cloud/account/TenantContext.html

```
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
import org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestAttributes;
import org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextHolder;
import com.sap.cloud.account.TenantContext;

public class ContextAwareCallable<T> implements Callable<T>
{
    private Callable<T> task;
    private TenantContext tenantContext;
    private String tenantId;
    private RequestAttributes context;

    public ContextAwareCallable(Callable<T> task, TenantContext tenantContext, RequestAttributes context)
    {
        this.task = task;
        this.tenantContext = tenantContext;
        this.context = context;
        if (tenantContext != null)
        {
            this.tenantId = tenantContext.getTenant().getId();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public T call() throws Exception
    {
        if (context != null)
        {
            RequestContextHolder.setRequestAttributes(context);
        }

        if (tenantId != null)
        {
            return tenantContext.execute(tenantId, task);
        }

        return task.call();
    }
}
```